# python 3 - reading and writing to an online file

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api

I am trying to learn how to read and write to a file on a database such as drop-box or Google drive, but am having great difficulty, here is what I have tried:

```
import urllib.request
data = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
for line in data:
    print(line)
```

What is in the google drive document (what i want it to print):

```
Hello

World
```

what it actually prints:

```
b'<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta property="og:title"
```

etc ...

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Is it a spreadsheet?

Comment: No it's a document, sadly. Would I be able to do this with a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just because you can crawl the Web doesn’t mean that you always should

You should use the official API for this task.

- Spreadsheet: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python
- Google Drive: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python
- Other Google products: https://developers.google.com/products/

Once you get the file you can use parsing libraries for example [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) (For HTML or XML parsing) to get the desired data from file. If the file is in other format (CSV, JSON etc.) then use the respective python modules.